# Specify stored procedure parameter with sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, stored-procedures

Let me preface by saying I'm not very knowledgeable about SQL and this made searching for an answer hard. I may be using the wrong 'wording.'

Given the following query to execute a stored procedure:

```
USE MyDB
SET NOCOUNT ON
    EXECUTE dbo.adm_ExecuteProcedure
        @installationID           = 12345,
        @monthOf                  = '03/01/2013'
GO
```

Can I use a `select` statement to dynamically look up 12345? The following does not work, but is what I am trying to do.

```
USE MyDB
SET NOCOUNT ON
    EXECUTE dbo.adm_ExecuteProcedure
        @installationID           = (select id from installs where name = 'foo'),
        @monthOf                  = '03/01/2013'
GO
```

I don't have permission to edit the stored procedure.

Comment: Which database system are you using? SQL = Structured Query Language is jsut a language - used by a great many database vendors....

Comment: @marc_s - I am using sql server 2008 and MSQLMS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare @id int;

select  @id = id 
from    installs 
where   name = 'foo';

EXECUTE dbo.adm_ExecuteProcedure
    @installationID           = @id,
    @monthOf                  = '03/01/2013';
```

Answer (score 0):

well, you can do it, but in the code calling the stored procedure... or even in any query of the stored procedure, and in that case you wouldn't need the parameter at all...

Answer (score 0):

Try storing it in a variable (syntax depends on your DB system)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is declare variable and select installationId in that variable from your select statement and then just use that variable while executing stored procedure. Did you got it.